# How to get the if the text is displayed on bold with selenium

Tags: c#, css, selenium-webdriver

I have a pdf document like this:

```
\<div class=**"cs6C976429"** style="width:671px;height:18px;line-height:17px;margin-top:98px;margin-left:94px;position:absolute;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;"\>
\<nobr\>INFORMATIONBOLD\</nobr\>\</div\>
```

```
\<style type="text/css"\>
.cs85480F5E {color:#000000 !important;background-color:transparent !important;border-left-style: none !important;border-top-style: none !important;border-right-style: none !important;border-bottom-style: none !important;font-family:'Times New Roman' !important; font-size:13px !important; font-weight:normal !important; font-style:normal !important;  !important;}
.cs8B56BD64 {color:#000000 !important;background-color:transparent !important;border-left-style: none !important;border-top-style: none !important;border-right-style: none !important;border-bottom-style: none !important;font-family:'Times New Roman' !important; font-size:15px !important; font-weight:bold !important; font-style:normal !important;  !important;}
**.cs6C976429** {color:#000000 !important;background-color:transparent !important;border-left-style: none !important;border-top-style: none !important;border-right-style: none !important;border-bottom-style: none !important;font-family:'Times New Roman' !important; font-size:15px !important; **font-weight:bold** !important; font-style:normal !important; padding-left:2px !important;}
.cs354AAA62 {color:#808080 !important;background-color:transparent !important;border-left-style: none !important;border-top-style: none !important;border-right-style: none !important;border-bottom-style: none !important;font-family:'Times New Roman' !important; font-size:16px !important; font-weight:bold !important; font-style:normal !important; padding-left:2px !important;padding-right:2px !important;}
\</style\>
```

I have to validate the INFORMATIONBOLD is in bold style by selenium, I found the style with the Xpath selector:

```
\//style\[@type='text/css'\]
```

I am not able to find a way to validate the specific class used before is with the bold style with Selenium C#

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Algorithm:** I can only give you an algorithm as am not a `c#` person.

1. Identify and store the desired element into a variable. You may probably use one of the below XPath expression to locate the element

```
//div[text()='INFORMATIONBOLD']
```

or:

```
//nobr[text()='INFORMATIONBOLD']
```

2. Store the font-weight CSS value into a variable as below

```
var fontWeight = webelement.GetCssValue("font-weight");
```

3. if fontWeight is greater than or equal to 700 THEN "Its bold"
4. Else "its not bold"

Comment: Thanks it worked, do you have some place where I can see what means the results? 
ie. 700, 400 etc

Comment: Check this - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight